# Is there maximum connection limit to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, database-connection

I finished my desktop application using ADO.NET and SQL Server 2008. I planned to run my application on 10 computers connected to a SQL Server database on a Windows 7 computer via a local network.

Is there any problem if all computers are running simultaneously?

And what about SQL Server connection pools?

Note that when I try to find active connections of my database on SQL Server using this command:

```
sp_who
```

I found more than 20 active connection .

Does this cause a problem ?

Comment: have a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31173/max-connections-sql-server-express-could-have

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows 7 runing SQL Server:**

It appears that only 20 simultaneous connections are allowed from other devices.([Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/concurrent-connections-on-windows-7/f8cf24db-b640-4916-8f06-d2be52edaf91)) However, depending on the applications that are running on these 20 devices, possibly more connections can be initiated and that can be causing what you see.

Also make sure that you are properly closing connections within your application as necesary and not leaving connections open unnecesarily.

**For any Windows Server OS, the following applies in case your need for simultaneous connections is greater:**

From [How to: Set User Connections (SQL Server Management Studio) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030(v=sql.100).aspx)

> To set user connections
>
> 1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and click Properties.
> 2. Click the Connections node.
> 3. Under Connections, in the Max number of concurrent connections box, type or select a value from 0 through 32767 to set the maximum number
>    of users that are allowed to connect simultaneously to the instance of
>    SQL Server.
> 4. Restart SQL Server.

Maximum connections, therefore, is 32,767 and this is true through SQL Server 2014.

You can run `sp_configure` to get the current running value as well.

Answer (score 0):

**If you're just looking at ten clients, SQL Server should be able to handle that.**

Beyond that, it's just a matter of designing for that kind of load. For instance, you want to make sure you've got the right locks happening at the right times. In essence, having multiple concurrent clients accessing the same database is the same as having multiple, concurrent threads accessing the same variables on a single machine. The database is a bit smarter than just, say, an `int`, but you'll still want to make sure you're on top of how things happen.

For instance, say you have a table for `Tasks` that you want to complete, and it has a column for the `ID` and one for the `LastCompleted` time. On a single client, you might want to write something that accesses it like this:

1. Fetch the next one which has `LastCompleted < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())`
2. Do that task, which takes five minutes
3. `UPDATE` the table to set `LastCompleted = GETDATE()`

You could then complete all tasks every hour, pretty easily.

However, if you were faced with multiple clients accessing, this would result in multiple clients grabbing the same task multiple times, and doing it concurrently. In that scenario, you'd probably want another column to indicate `InProgressAsOf` as a date, then you can retry orphaned tasks as necessary but you never risk overlapping things happening. And even with that, you'd probably want to use `OUTPUT` clauses on your `UPDATE` to make sure it was all atomic.

1. Fetch the result from `UPDATE Tasks SET InProgressAsOf = GETDATE() OUTPUT DELETED.* WHERE LastCompleted < DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()) AND InProgressAsOf < DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, GETDATE())`
2. Do that task, which takes five minutes
3. `UPDATE` the table to set `LastCompleted = GETDATE()`

But yes, as long as you're on top of those nuances of multithreaded operations, you should be fine running ten concurrent connections against the same database.